# Pegar as horas do dia

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte select para pegar as horas do dia

```
SELECT '00:00' AS A UNION 
SELECT '01:00' UNION
SELECT '02:00' UNION
SELECT '03:00' UNION
SELECT '04:00' UNION
SELECT '05:00' UNION
SELECT '06:00' UNION
SELECT '07:00' UNION
SELECT '08:00' UNION
SELECT '09:00' UNION
SELECT '10:00' UNION
SELECT '11:00' UNION
SELECT '12:00' UNION
SELECT '13:00' UNION
SELECT '14:00' UNION
SELECT '15:00' UNION
SELECT '16:00' UNION
SELECT '17:00' UNION
SELECT '18:00' UNION
SELECT '19:00' UNION
SELECT '20:00' UNION
SELECT '01:00' UNION
SELECT '22:00' UNION
SELECT '23:00'
```

Existe alguma outra mais simples para fazer isso?

Porque parece que ao juntar essa consulta como o que eu quero fazer fica meio lento.

Por exemplo:

```
         SELECT * FROM( 
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT '00:00' AS A UNION 
                    SELECT '01:00' UNION
                    SELECT '02:00' UNION
                    SELECT '03:00' UNION
                    SELECT '04:00' UNION
                    SELECT '05:00' UNION
                    SELECT '06:00' UNION
                    SELECT '07:00' UNION
                    SELECT '08:00' UNION
                    SELECT '09:00' UNION
                    SELECT '10:00' UNION
                    SELECT '11:00' UNION
                    SELECT '12:00' UNION
                    SELECT '13:00' UNION
                    SELECT '14:00' UNION
                    SELECT '15:00' UNION
                    SELECT '16:00' UNION
                    SELECT '17:00' UNION
                    SELECT '18:00' UNION
                    SELECT '19:00' UNION
                    SELECT '20:00' UNION
                    SELECT '01:00' UNION
                    SELECT '22:00' UNION
                    SELECT '23:00' 
                ) A
             )A
             LEFT JOIN( SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%H:%i' ) HORA
                       ,TRUNCATE( MAX( humidade ),2 ) MAX_HUMIDADE
                       ,TRUNCATE( MIN( humidade ),2 ) MIN_HUMIDADE
                   FROM medicao
                  WHERE DATE(date) = ?
                  GROUP BY HOUR(date)
                 ) B ON B.HORA = A.A
```

Tipo um last_day pra pegar a ultima data do mês

Comment: não pode por os valores numa tabela?

Comment: Não sei, estou tentando otimizar minha consulta

Comment: Não poderia tratar isto no PHP por exemplo? Pegar a hora de cada linha e ignorar os segundos? Só pra constar, vc esta usando o `as A` mais de uma vez, quero dizer, mesmo que implicito esta usando, isso provavelmente causaria ambiguidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então só seria preciso usar a tabela  que está no join? No php eu faria um for?

Comment: Então, o teu JOIN parece exatamente para agrupar por horas, até entendo a necessidade por cima, mas creio que sim, vc usaria um `for/while` para iterar e salvar as horas de forma agrupada, mas depende se é isso mesmo que eu entendi, se for outra coisa poderia me esclarecer? Tenho quase certeza que dá pra simplificar seu código bastante.

Comment: É porque quero trazer mesmo os horários que não tem valor, por exemplo das 01 as 15 tiveram valor, mas a partir das 16 ainda não tem, para mostrar no gráfico

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma será colocar isso numa tabela.

Penso que em `MySQL` funcionará da mesma forma que em `SQL` (caso contrário, será apenas necessário fazer um ou outro acerto):

```
DECLARE @Hora INT = 0

CREATE TABLE #tmpHorasDoDia
(
    Hora NVARCHAR(5)
)

WHILE @Hora < 24
BEGIN
    IF @Hora < 10
        INSERT INTO #tmpHorasDoDia VALUES('0' + CAST(@Hora AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ':00')
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO #tmpHorasDoDia VALUES(CAST(@Hora AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ':00')

    SET @Hora = @Hora + 1
END
```

Comment: Isso é uma tabela temporária?

Comment: Sim @adventistaam, é, mas pode criar uma tabela física se o objetivo for utilizá-la em outras consultas no futuro.

Comment: Como a sua experiência, fica mais rápido se criar uma tabela para fazer a comparação do que aqueles `unions` que eu criei?

Comment: Sim, depende da consulta, mas por norma utilizar _UNION_ nunca é bom para performance. Mas qual o seu objetivo com a consulta?

Comment: É porque quero trazer mesmo os horários que não tem valor, por exemplo das 01 as 15 tiveram valor, mas a partir das 16 ainda não tem, para mostrar no gráfico