# Juntar tabelas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

- Tenho uma tabela que possui os horários do dia

  ```
   SELECT * FROM horas
  ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tipo da coluna `hora` é `VARCHAR(5)`

- E uma consulta contendo os valores das horas

  ```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%H:%i' ) HORA
                         ,TRUNCATE( MAX( humidade ),2 ) MAX_HUMIDADE
                         ,TRUNCATE( MIN( humidade ),2 ) MIN_HUMIDADE
                     FROM medicao
                    WHERE DATE(date) = '2018-07-24'
                    GROUP BY HOUR(date)
  ```

Cujo resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Mas ao fazer o `join`das tabelas só vem uma tupla

  ```
   SELECT * FROM
     HORAS A
     LEFT JOIN 
     (  SELECT DATE_FORMAT( medicao.date, '%H:%i' ) HORA
         ,TRUNCATE( MAX( humidade ),2 ) MAX_HUMIDADE
         ,TRUNCATE( MIN( humidade ),2 ) MIN_HUMIDADE
     FROM medicao
     WHERE DATE(medicao.date) = '2018-07-24'
     GROUP BY HOUR(medicao.date)
   ) B ON B.HORA = A.HORA;
  ```

Cujo resultado é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dei início a essa questão [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317306/54152), caso alguém queria entender melhor

Comment: Com a `query` que você fez, a condição de pegar os dados das duas tabela é `B.HORA = A.HORA`. Na tabela `medicacao` os valores das `horas` são valores fechados, como `00:00`, `01:00`, ... . Então com a `query` que você fez, os valores da tabela `medicacao` só irão ser unidos quando a `hora` da tabela `hora` for igual. Veja que a tabela `hora`, além das horas fechadas, tem os minutos.

Comment: Verdadeee! Agora que percebi que eu cadastrei os valores de horas errado. Era isso mesmo.

Comment: Poste que resolveu o problema para finalizar a pergunta.

Comment: Mas foi você que me ajudou a enxergar, muito obrigado! Pode adicionar a resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Motivo do erro:**

Com a `query` que você fez, a condição de pegar os dados das duas tabela é `B.HORA = A.HORA`. Na tabela `medicacao` os valores das `horas` são valores fechados, como `00:00`, `01:00`, ... . Então com a `query` que você fez, os valores da tabela `medicacao` só irão ser unidos quando a `hora` da tabela `hora` for igual. Veja que a tabela hora, além das horas fechadas, tem os minutos.